# Drawing animation in a Nattable OverlayPainter

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I am trying to render a loading animation on top of a nattable. I use the OverLayPainter mechanism to draw a "glasspane" and some text on top of the table, and this works perfect:

```
public class MessageOverlay
implements IOverlayPainter {
....
@Override
public void paintOverlay(final GC gc, final ILayer layer) {
  this.currentGC = gc;
  this.currentLayer = layer;
  if (visible) {
    currentGC.setAlpha(200);
    currentGC.fillRectangle(0, 0, currentLayer.getWidth(), currentLayer
      .getHeight());
     drawMessage();

    if (withLoadingAnimation) {
      showAnimation = true;
    }
   } else {
     showAnimation = false;
   }
  }
}
```

However, the `paintOverlay` method is not called regularely but rather everytime the table changes.

To be able to display a smoothe animation, I added a new thread

```
final Thread animatorThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 / fps);
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        break;
      }

       display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (showAnimation && !currentGC.isDisposed()) {
            final Image currentImage = getNextImage();
            final int posX = currentGC.getClipping().width / 2
                - currentImage.getBounds().width;
            final int posY = currentGC.getClipping().height / 2
                - currentImage.getBounds().height;
            currentGC.drawImage(currentImage, posX, posY);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

animatorThread.start();
```

As you can see it tries to access the graphics context `this.currentGC` set in the  `paintOverlay` method. My problem is, that `currentGC` within the `animatorThread` is always `disposed`.

How can I a.) ensure that the context is not disposed in the thread or b.) solve this in an alternative way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even if the GC was not disposed this would still fail with 'Invalid thread access' as all UI operations (such as `drawImage`) must be done in the UI thread.

Comment: ahh you are absolutely right, i have changed the question to reflect running in the ui thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a new GC with the current NatTable instance and if needed pass the config from the passed in GC instance. Then you are in charge of disposing the GC instance and should not have the risk of a disposed GC outside your thread.

A simple example could look like the following snippet that simply shows the pane for 1000ms and then removes it again. You need of course to change the logic to be more dynamic with regards to your loading operation then:

```
AtomicBoolean paneThreadStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

...

natTable.addOverlayPainter(new IOverlayPainter() {

    @Override
    public void paintOverlay(GC gc, ILayer layer) {
        if (this.paneThreadStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GC currentGC = new GC(natTable);
                    currentGC.setForeground(GUIHelper.COLOR_WHITE);
                    currentGC.setBackground(GUIHelper.COLOR_BLACK);
                    currentGC.setAlpha(200);
                    currentGC.fillRectangle(0, 0, layer.getWidth(), layer.getHeight());

                    String load = "Loading data ...";
                    Point textExtent = currentGC.textExtent(load);
                    currentGC.drawText(load,
                            layer.getWidth() / 2 - textExtent.x / 2,
                            layer.getHeight() / 2 - textExtent.y / 2,
                            true);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    currentGC.dispose();
                    natTable.redraw();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This way you are able to show the pane again by changing the `AtomicBoolean` from the outside:

```
    Button showPaneButton = new Button(buttonPanel, SWT.PUSH);
    showPaneButton.setText("Show Pane");
    showPaneButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            this.paneThreadStarted.set(false);
            natTable.redraw();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems to be getting me closer to the result, however, the layer is now not drawn over the table but over the window. I was able to correctly set the clipping (so the overlay has the correct size). I create the new gc with ``new GC(table.getShell)``.  If I use ``new GC(table.getDisplay)`` I do not see any overlay, probably because it is drawn underneath the table?

Comment: Have you tried `new GC(natTable);`? Because NatTable as a `Canvas` is also a `Drawable`

Comment: This sounds like the right place to put it, however, it seems like the overlay is drawn underneath the actual table, thus hiding the content of the overlay.

Comment: Maybe a concurrency issue as you render asynchronously in a second thread. I tested with a simple adaption of your code and it worked for me. If you still have issues you could try a PaintListener instead of an IOverlayPainter.

Comment: would you mind sharing your example? I could analyse the differences, if any and see if I am making a subtle mistake.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem, I use the provided GC for the drawing of the overla in ``paintOverlay`` method and create an new GC in the animation thread. It's not perfect yet, but it works

Comment: hmm maybe i was to soon in stating that I had the solution. May I ask where you create your GC(natTable)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193517/discussion-between-bwright-and-dirk-fauth).